# How to in-place update values in multiple columns in a DataFrame on condition from another using assignment operator?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pass-by-reference

There is one DataFrame `S` to be updated:

```
n ii      a  b     c
0 True   10 11  1.20 
1 False   2  0   NaN
2 True   34 75  2.14
3 True   22 88  0.02
```

from another DataFrame `T` with another set of columns

```
 a  b     c
 8 13  1.19
31 72  2.10
20 83  0.05
```

Is it possible to have `S` updated in a function with one line assignment statement?

```
def process(S):
    ii = S.ii
    # ... internal calculations that produce T
    columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    S[ii][columns] = T[columns] # < ----- in-place update
```

That `process` works on a pass-by-reference approach leaving `S` updated after a call

```
process(S)
```

Comment: update only those rows where ii is True.. ?

Comment: @iamklaus yes, only those rows with ii is True

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the dataframe:

```
    def process(S):
        ii = S.ii
        # ... internal calculations that produce T
        columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        S.loc[ii, columns] = T[columns] # < ----- in-place update
        return S
```

And call the function like this:

```
    S = process(S)
```

Comment: yes, I wanted to have it in-place modification instead, and neither S[ii] approach is applicable as a one line statement due to "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Comment: What if you change S[ii][columns] to S.loc[ii, columns]